# How to paginate depend on container height in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to auto paginate depend on container height in jquery.
I want to make a pagination depending on div height,I am adding a example but that's made on angularjs. Can anybody help me how can i make it using jquery insteadof angularjs.

```
<div class="content" id="main_content">
    <p>Text 1</p>
    <p>Text 2</p>
    <p>Text 3</p>
    <p>Text 4</p>
    <p>Text 5</p>
    <p>Text 6</p>
    <p>Text 7</p>
</div>
```

Want to make previous code like this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pjvdogoo/9/, but by using jquery.

Comment: Is the height set with css?

Comment: No actually height can be anything, it's not fixed, basically i need it for responsive design. Thanks